# How to get and lock next identity value SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to develop a small winform software C# with SQL Server 2008 R2 which runs on 3 computers.

I have designed the "Customer_Master" table with a `INDENTITY type primay key(CusId)`.

What I want is, lets say when I open a customer registration form then the program should display the next id value. I can get the next identity value by using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.
But in this case, as I used a centralized system, if all the computers try to create a new customer at the same time it will show the same key at their registration form. But if they got register a new customer the registered id will be different from what was shown.

So I want to lock the next identity value register the Customer with the id which is shown in the form.
How to do this. Is there any way to manage concurrent inserts.
I am using C# and SQL Server R2 Express.

Please help me solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is there a requirement to tell people what the identity value will be in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need the ID *before* the record is inserted?  If not, then SCOPE_IDENTITY will work fine.  If the insert of the new record works, then SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the id of the record that the client inserted (not any other clients).

If you *do* need the ID beforehand, then you could insert a "stub" record as a placeholder until the client writes the "real" customer record.  In this way, each client could essentially reserve the ID before writing the actual data.

This is not a good idea, however, as it can lead to a lot of garbage data in your table.

Answer (score 2):

Not with using IDENTITY, what you "want" is not possible with INT IDENTITY as the next sequence is determined as the INSERT is EXECUTED.  You also cannot "guess" at what the next number is because there is **no guarantee** that the identity will be contiguous.  I don't think this is a very wise decision but if you really want this then you would need to create a table that's whole purpose to sequentially increment and use that value as your PK and remove the IDENTITY specification from the Customer_Master table.

Comment: Thanks..I don't necessarily need the identity value. I can use just a non identity primary key column. After that what is the way to do what i hv said above.